# Couldn't generate mvn site with profile

Tags: maven, report, findbugs

I have a problem with generate site using my specific profile. My profile settings looks like that:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>codequality</id>
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>../target/site/${project.name}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                        <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                        <effort>Max</effort>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dashboard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>        
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

when I run cmd: **mvn site -P codequality**, the site is generated but the findbugs reports aren't there. It contains this:

```
target/
└── site
    ├── css
    │   ├── maven-base.css
    │   ├── maven-theme.css
    │   ├── print.css
    │   └── site.css
    └── images
        ├── collapsed.gif
        ├── expanded.gif
        ├── external.png
        ├── icon_error_sml.gif
        ├── icon_info_sml.gif
        ├── icon_success_sml.gif
        ├── icon_warning_sml.gif
        ├── logos
        │   ├── build-by-maven-black.png
        │   ├── build-by-maven-white.png
        │   └── maven-feather.png
        └── newwindow.png
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

First why do you change the output folder for the site generation? Furthermore you didn't give the information to the findbugs plugin, cause it will use the current target/ folder (default: ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}) instead of the given one.